# Material UI Table footer to stick at the bottom of TableContainer, not the bottom of tableBody

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to separate the `TableFooter` component from `MUI Table` from the `TableRow` group.
the codesandbox below is a basic implementation of a table and my latest attempt to tackle the issue (trying to add a separator between the body and footer:
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-scott-gcrhxk?file=/src/TableAndDrawer.tsx

Is there a way to stick the `TableFooter` to the bottom of the `TableContainer`? for reference, there is a MUI component `TablePagination` which does this exact thing, but isnt customizable. The idea is of course for the footer to be sticky at the bottom, meaning if there are more rows than space, the rows will scroll below the footer.

has anyone tackled this issue? is this even possible? I am assuming there is a CSS property that needs to be overriden within MUI, which is what I guess `TablePagination` does.